# Change AS400, Synon and JDedwards default language

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg, jdedwards, iseries-navigator

The AS400 systems are V5R3 and have Spanish as the primary language and English as the secondary. 
We have Synon and JDEdwards installed on system with Spanish as the primary language and English as the secondary.

So please let me know how I can switch between both languages I tried Option "CHGSYSLIBL QSYS2924" but it will only change language for Error text message

I want to use system in such a way that User will use their Spanish language version and we will use English language version to work on AS400, Synon and JDEdwards?

Comment: I believe Synon has it's own language libraries. Not sure about JDEdwards. And, I suspect you have to deal with each application separately.

Comment: yes Sysnon has separate library. i need steps or command for each to change language from Spanish to English.

Answer (score 0):

For me, running `LANG` command in AS400 changes languages between Primary and Secondary.